Unable to correctly visualize a PostGIS Out-DB COG Raster from private AWS S3 bucket on QGIS canvas
I cloud-optimized two similar TIFF files (small SRTM tiles) with GDAL and checked their validity as per here.
I created an AWS IAM account giving it read-only access on S3 buckets and generated access key for this account.
I configured AWS (using AWS CLI) setting the correct keys and region.
I created a public and a private bucket on S3 and put a raster in each bucket/raster folder
Now I can:

Access the gdalinfo of both rasters from GDAL passing the correct AWS key/secret.
Correctly load both rasters in QGIS (added AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in QGIS env variables and using AWS3 protocol for the private and HTTP/S for the public).
Correctly load both rasters out-db into a local installation of PostgreSQL into a db_name.schema with the following commands as per here.

For private bucket (/vsis3)
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=access_key_for_reader_user \
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_access_key_for_the_reader_user \
raster2pgsql \
  -s 4326 \
  -t 512x512 \
  -I \
  -R \
  -C \
  -M \
  /vsis3/bucket_name/folder/raster1_cog.tif \
  schema.raster1_cog \
  | psql -h localhost -d db_name -U postgres -p 5432

For the public bucket (/vsicurl)
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=access_key_for_reader_user \
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_access_key_for_the_reader_user \
raster2pgsql \
  -s 4326 \
  -t 512x512 \
  -I \
  -R \
  -C \
  -M \
  /vsicurl/https://bucket_name.s3.region.amazonaws.com/folder/raster2_cog.tif \
  schema.raster2_cog \
  | psql -h localhost -d db_name -U postgres -p 5432

Now in QGIS (connected via Authentication Manager to the db_name with postgres user) when I try to load the public bucket raster, at first I get the following connection error (and nothing goes to the canvas showing weird min/max values for a raster in the layer panel)
bad connection, not retrying
connection still bad after reset.
Error fetching tile index from backend.

Removing the layer from the layer panel and loading it again it’s properly shown on the canvas (showing the correct min and max for the raster in the layer panel).
When I try to load the private bucket one, I am never able to have it shown correctly (no even after many reload as I did for the public case) and the log says
ERROR: rt_band_load_offline_data: Cannot open offline raster: /vsis3/bucket_name/folder/raster1_cog.tif

The raster appears to be correctly queried by ST_BandPath(rast) or ST_Envelope(rast) from QGIS SQL window but when loaded nothing shows up in the canvas.
I should also mention that
ALTER DATABASE db_name SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = true;
ALTER DATABASE db_name SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers TO 'ENABLE_ALL';

and
SET postgis.gdal_vsi_options = 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= access_key_for_reader_user AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_access_key_for_the_reader_user';

For the active session, did not change the result.
Possibly related to this unanswered question.
System specs:

Fedora Linux 40 (Workstation)
postgresql16-server-16.3
postgis-3.4.2
postgis-client-3.4.2
qgis-3.34.6-1.fc40.x86_64

